# Animate/move multiple cars(markers) on map like UBER

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, material-design

I'm looking to animate/move multiple cars(markers) on the map like UBER while I'm getting their updated locations from API calling every 10 seconds when API response comes I want to animate/move every car(marker) on his direction.

For now, I was able to animate/move one car(marker) smoothly. But I struggled when they are multiple, by  keeping their old locations

```
int driverArraySize = driverArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < driverArraySize; i++){
                JSONObject driverJson = driverArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String driver_id = driverJson.getString("_id");
                JSONArray driverLocation = driverJson.getJSONArray("driverLocation");}
```

I have this array contains driver ids and their current locations, can I use these data to animate/move?

```
private void animateCars(final Marker marker, final LatLng beganPosition, final LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
    if (marker != null) {
        final LatLng startPosition = new LatLng(beganPosition.latitude, beganPosition.longitude);
        final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(finalPosition.latitude, finalPosition.longitude);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(20000); // duration in second
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation){
                try {
                    float v = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                    marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                    marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                    Float rotation = getBearing(startPosition, new LatLng(finalPosition.latitude, finalPosition.longitude));
                    if (!Float.isNaN(rotation)) {
                        marker.setRotation(rotation);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //I don't care atm..
                }
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);                
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}

public static float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

    if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
    else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
    return -1;
}
```

and this is the code i'm using for animating

Comment: I solved my problem 

Answer (score 1):

Look for this two options. They can be helpfull

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAotyuaOAb0&t=559s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USLWs8o3-Ow&t=323s